# Gulp "unsupported gulp version" issue

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am currently working on an old project I've made 3 years ago. But when I want to run a gulp command "watch" it gives me an "Unsupported gulp version" message in my terminal. With no additional information.

A few weeks ago I didn't have any problems with starting the project, but I think since I've updated my gulp version I started having this issue.

I have no knowledge in how to convert gulpfiles etc so I'm not sure how to update my gulpfile or whatnot.

If I type "gulp -v" I get:

```
CLI version 2.0.1
Local version 4.0.0
```

This is the gulpfile currently:

```
var gulp      = require("gulp"),
  include     = require("gulp-include"),
  coffee      = require("gulp-coffee"),
  compass     = require("gulp-compass"),

  uglify      = require("gulp-uglify"),
  mincss      = require("gulp-minify-css");


//////////////////
// DEVELOPMENT //
////////////////

// Scripts
gulp.task("scripts", function() {
  console.log("-- gulp is running task 'scripts'");

  gulp.src("public-source/javascripts/app.coffee")
    .pipe(include())
      .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(coffee())
      .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public/javascripts"));
});

// Styles
gulp.task("styles", function() {
  console.log("-- gulp is running task 'styles'");
  gulp.src("public-source/stylesheets/main.scss")
    .pipe(compass({
      css: "public/stylesheets",
      sass: "public-source/stylesheets",
      assets: "public-source/images",
      image: "public/images"
    }))
      .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public/stylesheets"));
});

// Watcher
gulp.task("watch", function() {
  console.log("-- GULP IS WATCHING");
  gulp.watch(["public-source/javascripts/**"], ["scripts"]);
  gulp.watch(["public-source/stylesheets/**", "public-source/images/**"], ["styles"]);
});

////////////
// TASKS //
//////////

gulp.task("default", ["scripts", "styles"]);
gulp.task("deploy", ["deploy-scripts", "deploy-styles"]);
```

Might not be the most beautifull gulpfile but I need to get it working. But my knowledge with gulp on it's own is very lackluster so any help would be really appreciated.

If I have to provide more information, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just hit the same issue. For me at least, the issue was that I had `gulp-cli` installed globally but `gulp` installed locally. I'd updated the local instance but not the global one.

Updating the global `gulp-cli` fixed the issue.